# how to set perpage automatically based on my data?

Tags: reactjs, react-admin

```
<Grid item xs={6}>
              <ReferenceInput
                fullWidth
                reference='products'
                source='product_id'
                validate={[required()]}
                className={classes.input}
              >
                <AutocompleteInput optionText={(option) => option.name + ' (' + option.denomination + ')'} />
              </ReferenceInput>
```

I dont know for sure how many data that i would have because it will increase every day and its probably up to 1000. So any suggestion to set my perpage in reference input?

Comment: Your question is not clear. please edit it and make it clear.

Comment: is it clear now? @Dipten

Comment: from what I can tell, what you're look for is a concept called pagination and it's implemented at the server side. Which language are you using for the backend?

Comment: you can tell me how many is the maximum of perpage in reference input react admin @DebarghaRoy

Comment: i would suggest starting here - https://marmelab.com/react-admin/List.html#the-pagination-component . and put some code samples for us to see to find out where you are not getting the solution.